# Best Practices for accessing private methods in the revealing module pattern

Tags: javascript, scope, private, revealing-module-pattern

Almost every revealing module pattern tutorial that I've seen will show a public method access a private method **without** using "method.**call**(this,...)".

This seems to get the job done alright, but if you do a trace(this) in the private method, it will show "Window". This feels like a potential gotcha.

Should I be using `call` (or `apply`), or would this be introducing unneeded complexity?

plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/hc3ZPJyeHcT9bLbLaLpX?p=preview

EDIT: My thinking is that by using "call", it somehow makes it "safer" since the context is the api object rather than the global namespace.

```
var Module = (function () {

    var _privateVar = "PRIVATE!";

    var api = {
        publicMethod: publicMethod
    }

    return api;

    function publicMethod() {
        privateMethod();
        privateMethod.call(this);
    };

    function privateMethod(message) {
        console.log(_privateVar, this);
    };


})();

Module.publicMethod();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no best practise. Both

```
function privateFunction(self, message) { // also popular: `that`
    // do something with `self`
}
…
privateFunction(this, …);
```

and

```
function privateMethod(message) {
    // do something with `this`
}
…
privateMethod.call(this, …);
```

are fine. Just stick to one style and keep your code base consistent. However, the first one might be more popular because many private functions are actually static and don't need an instance to work with, so it simplifies things to use explicit parameters for the instance (instead of assuming/hoping that the function is called with the expected `this` value).

Comment: Being explicit seems best. However, I did notice one small advantage to using call -  when using a debugger, you can conveniently get immediate access of getters via the  "this" object

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this for the last couple of days, and was happy to come across this question. However, after some experimenting, none of the answers seem satisfactory for at least one case: passing data between the public and private function.

Below are three examples, using 'call', 'bind' and a plain call. Binding seems to be the only way to keep the private method in the local scope, and also allow data exchange between private and public methods. The other suggestion, of passing the context to the private method, would still leave the private method executing outside the module (If I understood it correctly).

Interestingly, using a plain call (with/without strict mode) allows data exchange, even when the private method's context is 'undefined'/'window'.

Using 'bind':

```
"use strict"; 
var home = (function(){

  var bob = function(){
    console.log("Bob's scope: " + Object.keys(this));  // "Bob's scope: init"
    var bob_says = "Hello";
    var fBound = alice.bind(this);
    var alice_reply = fBound(bob_says);
    console.log("Alice answered: " + alice_reply);     // "Alice answered: Hello Bob"
  };

  var alice = function(bob_greeting){
    var scope = this ? Object.keys(this) : this;
    console.log("Alice's scope: " + scope);            // "Alice's scope: init"
    console.log("Bob said: " + bob_greeting);          // "Bob said: Hello"
    return bob_greeting + " Bob"; 
  };

  return { init : bob };
})();

home.init();
```

Using 'call':

```
"use strict"; 
var home = (function(){

  var bob = function(){
    console.log("Bob's scope: " + Object.keys(this));  // "Bob's scope: init"
    var bob_says = "Hello"; 
    var alice_reply = alice.call(this, bob_says);
    console.log("Alice answered: " + alice_reply);     // "Alice answered: undefined Bob"
  };

  var alice = function(self, bob_greeting){
    var scope = this ? Object.keys(this) : this;
    console.log("Alice's scope: " + scope);            // "Alice's scope: init"
    console.log("Bob said: " + bob_greeting);          // "Bob said: undefined"
    return bob_greeting + " Bob"; 
  };

  return { init : bob };
})();

home.init();
```

Without call or bind:

```
"use strict";
var home = (function(){

  var bob = function(){
    console.log("Bob's scope: " + Object.keys(this));  // "Bob's scope: init"
    var bob_says = "Hello"; 
    var alice_reply = alice(bob_says);
    console.log("Alice answered: " + alice_reply);     // "Alice answered: Hello Bob"
  };

  var alice = function(bob_greeting){
    var scope = this ? Object.keys(this) : this;
    console.log("Alice's scope: " + scope);            // "Alice's scope: undefined"
    console.log("Bob said: " + bob_greeting);          // "Bob said: Hello"
    return bob_greeting + " Bob"; 
  };

  return { init : bob };
})();

home.init();
```

Update and possible answer.
    I was curious to see if, when Alice is called without 'call' or 'bind', and her context is undefined (or window), does she have access to private variables in 'home'? Yes, so my tentative answer to the OP (and myself) is to just call the private function normally: no 'bind', no 'call' and no need to pass in the context, but to "use strict" if it bugs you to see the window context popping up while running the private function. It appears that no new property is being created in 'window', and there are no clashes if the window has an object with the same name as the private function (whether strict mode is on or off). If there are gotcha's, I have not come across them yet.

```
"use strict";

var alice = "Hi, I'm global's Alice"; 

var home = (function(){

  var bob = function(){
    console.log("Bob's scope: " + Object.keys(this)); // "Bob's scope: init" 
    var bob_says = "Hello";
    var alice_reply = alice(bob_says);
    console.log("Alice answered: " + alice_reply);    // "Alice answered: Hello Bob. I'm in the garage."
  };

  var alice_location = "in the garage.";

  var alice = function(bob_greeting){
    var scope = this ? Object.keys(this) : this;
    console.log("Alice's scope: " + scope);           // "Alice's scope: undefined"
    console.log("Bob said: " + bob_greeting);         // "Bob said: Hello"
    return bob_greeting + " Bob. I'm " + alice_location; 
  };

  return { init : bob };

})();

home.init();

console.log(alice);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `Module` is never in its own context, therefor calling a static function of it will result in `this` being the global object.

--

You can *try* to fix that like so (by creating a "newable" object):

```
const Module = (function () {
    var _privateVar = "PRIVATE!";

    const Api = function () {

    };

    function publicMethod() {
        privateMethod();
        privateMethod.call(this);
    };

    function privateMethod(message) {
        console.log(_privateVar, this);
    };

    Api.protoype.publicMethod = publicMethod;

    return Api;
});

const module = new Module();

console.log(module.publicMethod());
```

Comment: Do you say "try" because it isn't really advisable (to "new up" a revealing module pattern)? Seems awkward to do that.

Comment: You should not call a function that is not a constructor with `new`. Your `Module` is a factory function that returns an object, so using `new` is pointless. It doesn't change the context of the `privateMethod` anyway.

Comment: It returns a function and not an object

Comment: @Neal I wrote "object" because `new` cares about object vs primitive values, of course a function is an object.